# Upgrading to Gulp 4 from Gulp 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've attempted to update the gulpfile below to Gulp v4 from v3 but am still getting an error: `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: client`

Not sure what I am missing but realise that the functions may not be written correctly. The tasks in series are correct I believe: `gulp.task('build', gulp.series('client', 'sass'));`  for example.

```
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('build', gulp.series('client', 'sass'));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('client-watch', 'sass-watch'));

gulp.task('server', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server/index',
    ext: 'js json'
  });
});

gulp.task('client', function () {
  gulp.src('client/js/main.js')
      .pipe(browserify({
        transform: ['hbsfy'],
        extensions: ['.hbs']
      }))
      .pipe(rename('hearthclone.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/build'));
});

gulp.task('client-watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('client/js/**/*.js', ['client']);
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('client/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass-watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('client/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'server', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `gulp.task` form of defining tasks (rather that as functions) then you cannot refer to those tasknames until after they have been declared.  That would be a `forward reference` (see below).  So just put your

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('client', 'sass'));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('client-watch', 'sass-watch'));
```

after all those tasks have been defined.  I recommend right before the `default` task line.

See https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series#forward-references

> **Forward references**
>
> A forward reference is when you compose tasks, using string
> references, that haven't been registered yet. This was a common
> practice in older versions, but this feature was removed to achieve
> faster task runtime and promote the use of named functions.
>
> In newer versions, you'll get an error, with the message "Task never
> defined", if you try to use forward references. You may experience
> this when trying to use exports for your task registration and
> composing tasks by string. In this situation, use named functions
> instead of string references.